# How to write a Character type concept?

Tags: c++, character, c++20, c++-concepts

The standard library doesn't seem to provide a concept for character types yet. Similar to e.g. [`std::integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/integral), I want a concept that is suitable for character types (such as `char`, `wchar_t`, `char32_t`, etc.). How should one write a proper concept for this purpose?

Something similar to this could help:

```
template <typename T>
concept Character = std::integral<T> && sizeof( T ) <= 4;
```

But I feel like the above is not sufficient. I guess it should have more constraints.

Comment: you can list them one by one.

Comment: Note that `long`, `int`, and `short` (and, of course, their unsigned variants) can all have a size that's `<= 4`.

Comment: @Pete Becker That's why I feel like this one is not good enough.

Comment: Check if `T` has a valid [`char_traits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/char_traits) specialization?

Comment: `std::is_same_v<T,char>` etc... @PeteBecker Note that bool is also considered integral `static_assert(std::is_integral_v<bool>);` which is somewhat surprising.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template< class T >
concept Character = 
    /* true if T is same as the listed char types below
     * do not forget that e.g. same_as<char, T> is true only
     * when T is char and not char&, unsigned char, const char
     * or any combination (cvref),
     * therefore we only remove the const volatile specifiers
     * but not the reference (like in is_integral) */
    std::same_as< char, std::remove_cv_t<T> > ||
    /* do for each char type, 
     * see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Character_types */;
```

---

Based on the discussion below:

I would say if you introduce a character trait, it would be a good idea to do it like the standard does for e.g. integral types. CV-qualified, signed or unsigned. But not a reference to an integral type, like pointer, which is not that specific type that it points to.

Therefore my suggestion would be a proper (standard conform) type trait for all character types (signed/unsigned, cv-qualified).

To restrict the type of a member variable, there are other methods to achieve that, either through a type constraint (`requires`) or an assertion (`static_assert`) or by simply removing the cv-qualifiers.

**e.g.**

```
template <Character C>
requires !(std::is_const_v<C> || std::is_volatile_v<C>)
class Foo { static C var = '$'; };
```

or

```
template <Character C>
class Foo { 
    static_assert(
        !(std::is_const_v<C> || std::is_volatile_v<C>),
        "No cv types allowed."
    );
    static C var = '$'; 
};
```

or

```
template <Character C>
class Foo { 
    using char_type = std::remove_cv_t<C>;
    static char_type var = '$'; 
};
```

Comment: Tnx. So I have to remove the cv qualifier? So that e.g. when `const char` is passed to the concept, it works but for `char&` or `const char&` not work?

Comment: @digito_evo Exactly. More specific, for each char type you've listed. You could also allow references if it fits your needs (then use std::remove_cvref_t).

Comment: No, I don't think references make any sense for my use case. I need this `Character` concept so that I can use it in the definition of class templates (things like `template <Character char_type> class Foo { static char_type var = '$'; };`). Do you think I should use `std::remove_cvref_t` for such cases?

Comment: I would not recommend it. The best is to be standard conform as possible, then other users will intuitively know of what is meant (hopefully). But if you want a reference in your struct, then you would have to use the requires clause and remove the reference when you pass the type (e.g. `requires Character<std::remove_reference_t<char_type>>`). In the end: your choice.

Comment: Is there a way so that I can write the `Character` concept the way you have written and also prevent cv-qualified type template arguments (e.g. `const char`) from being passed to a class template? Basically, I want to keep the concept standard confirm as you said but still prevent the class from being instantiated using cv-qualified template arguments. Because it should not happen in my code.

Comment: That would be `same_as< char, T >`, no reference and no cv-qualified types. If you want to allow cv-types, then remove the cv-qualifiers `same_as< char, remove_cv_t<T> >` and on top of that, if you want to allow references also `same_as< char, remove_cvref<T> >`. Hope it's much clearer now.`

Comment: And don't worry about standard conformity. You do what you need to do. If your specification says, that no cv-types are allowed, then so be it.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. It solved all my problems. I guess I'll take the first approach (using the requires clause) since it's shorter and also doesn't add any code to the body of the class. It's really clean and concise.

Comment: Yep, if you want to restrict use the first one, if you want to assure that no cv qualifiers are accidentally added use the third version, but if you want the first approach and want to have your own message on the screen, take the second.

Answer (score 3):

Since `std::char_traits` doesn't forbid instantiation for types other than character types, I believe you have to list it all by yourself.

```cpp
template <typename T>
concept Character = 
    std::same_as<T, char> ||
    std::same_as<T, signed char> ||
    std::same_as<T, unsigned char> ||
    std::same_as<T, wchar_t> ||
    std::same_as<T, char8_t> ||
    std::same_as<T, char16_t> ||
    std::same_as<T, char32_t>;
```

Comment: Thanks Nimrod, didn't know the `same_as`  concept yet (I was still stuck at `std::is_same_v` traits)

Comment: Tnx for the suggestions. Also, do you think the answer by Erdal Küçük is more correct?

Comment: @digito_evo not more correct but more standard conform (e.g. is_integral removes only the const volatile specifiers). It depends on how you want to implement it.

Comment: Yes, I admit his answer is more standard-conformed.